# Create custom writable key/value type in python for Hadoop Map Reduce?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I have worked on Hadoop MR for quite some time and I have created and used custom(extension) `Writable` classes including `MapWritable`. Now I am required to translate the same MR that I have written in Java to Python. I do not have experience in python and am now exploring the various libraries for the same. I am looking into some options like **Pydoop** and **Mrjob**. However, I want to know if  these libraries contain the option to create similar custom `Writable` classes and how to create them. If not, what possible alternatives exist to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Pydoop, **explicit** support for custom Hadoop types is still [WIP](https://github.com/crs4/pydoop/issues/270). In other words, right now we're not making things easy for the user, but it can be done with a bit of work. A couple of pointers:

- Pydoop already includes custom Java code, auto-installed together with the Python package as `pydoop.jar`. We pass this extra jar to Hadoop as needed. Adding more Java code is a matter of placing the source in `src/` and listing it in `JavaLib.java_files` in `setup.py`
- On the Python side, you need deserializers for the new types. See for instance `LongWritableDeserializer` in `pydoop.mapreduce.pipes`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, I found an issue while building the library for python 3.6 by cloning the develop branch of pydoop. JAVA_HOME not set. I am running the build as root user. I have set the value of JAVA_HOME and HADOOP_HOME in .bash_profile. I am using Hortonworks 2.6.5. The hadoop_env.sh also has JAVA_HOME value set correctly. However I still keep getting this issue. Is there anything else that I need to do?

Comment: @KNP this is SO, not a Pydoop help page. If you think you have found an issue with the installation process, pleas open a ticket at https://github.com/crs4/pydoop/issues

Comment: Correction. It was a mistake from my side. I had export statements wrong in the bashrc file. Missed the export keyword. Stupid of me. Corrected it and it worked.