# API libraries for map reduce applications with HBase using python or scala?

Tags: python, scala, mapreduce, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform

I have seen that there are `API`s like `Hadoop streaming`, `dumbo`, `hadoopy` etc for writing `MR` applications with python.

I am starting with `python` language due to client request and my question is to see if there are `API`s available to work with `HBase`. I have seen some places that have libraries but they are working on much older versions of `HBase`, still on `0.9x` version of `HBase`, [HappyBase](http://happybase.readthedocs.io/en/latest/news.html) for example.

I want to know if there are any libraries available that I can work with for `HDP 2.6.5`. My operations involve using `MR` with `combiner`, [`MultiTableOutputFormat`](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/MultiTableOutputFormat.html), [custom writable classes as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51643536/6162224).

I have worked with `Java` before and right now, heading onto a new language and want to be able to do these things using `python` as well. Are there any libraries that support them with `HBase`?

Similarly, are there options for `Scala` as well for the same version of `HDP`? Although, this part is not very critical at the moment.

PS: [I had posted a question about this in `Hortonworks` community weeks ago, but no responses yet.](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/208063/are-there-api-libraries-available-for-programming.html)

Comment: Did you consider using Spark ? You could connect to HBASE and use pyspark ou Spark with Scala

Comment: Spark sounds like a nice option. We haven't considered that yet. I will look into that. However, our operations are strictly batch processing from disk, I wasn't sure if Spark would be the ideal choice for it.

Comment: Well, I used it for exactly this use case: Batch processing from disk. And using Python to distribute workload across a cluster with only 10-12 lines of code was awesome ;) BTW, we use it in production and it didn't fail us for months. Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-using-spark-query-hbase

Comment: @gcharbon Thank you. I will check this out.